# Graphql mistakes string type field argument for ID type

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am getting type error on graphql argument field that's been defined as string. Strangely it expects ID type instead.

Argument field in question: `createdBy`

- When I type in random ID that I get from for example mongodb it proceeds, thinking it's ID type.
- Renaming my field to something else for example `createdUsername` it works as expected, receiving strings properly.

I wish to keep the name `createdBy` as it is string type and wondering what's causing the weird type, name collision issue. Any help is appreciated.

I am using koa, koa-graphql, and bare graphql on my backend.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code for my input type definition:

```
const clientFilterInputFields = {
   type: {type: GraphQLID},
   company: { type: GraphQLString },
   person: { type: GraphQLString },
   phone: { type: GraphQLString },
   email: { type: GraphQLString },
   social: { type: GraphQLString },
   createdBy: { type: GraphQLString },
   createdAt: { type: dateInputType }
}

const clientFilterInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
   name: 'clientFilterInput',
   fields: clientFilterInputFields
})

export const getClientsArgs = {
   clientFilterInput: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(clientFilterInputType) },
   pagingInput: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(pagingInputType) }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have that defines the schema

Comment: Yes sir, I have made an edit.

Comment: Turns out it was mongodb error down the line in the resolver function. `new ObjectId(createdBy)`. They throw the same error message. I am sorry :>.